# extjs 4 how to declare a global variable from a store

Tags: variables, extjs4, store, global

We have an extJs4 - spring MVC application. 
I would like to declare a variable with user information (name, firstname, role). With role we can set field in read only or to hidde some part of the application.

In my app.js:

```
Ext.application({
   name: 'appname',
   appFolder: 'js/app',
   enableQuickTips:true,
   controllers: [
              'MainController',....

              ],
   autoCreateViewport: true,
   globals:
      var1 : 5    //it works for simple variable

});
```

I would like to create store variable with this

```
var appglobalstore = Ext.getStore('MyStore');
```

This is not possible :

```
globals:
     appglobalstore : Ext.getStore('MyStore');
```

And to get value in extjs  like that (I guess)

```
var role= appname.app.globals.role
```

Is it possible ? Or if it's not possible,  whereever I need the role do I have to declare ? like that

```
var role = Ext.getStore('myStore').getAt(0).raw.role;
```

Answer (score 2):

The name given to your app is the name of the global variable that ExtJS provides to you.

So, you can do that:

```
appname.role = role = Ext.getStore('myStore').getAt(0).raw.role;
```

Then you can access to your role by:

```
var x = appname.role;
```

And you can assign your value to "appname.role" in the launch attribute of your application:

```
Ext.application({
   name: 'appname',
   appFolder: '/extjs-app/app',
   controllers: [
      'MainController', ..
   ],
   requires: [
      'appname.utils.Logger', ...
   ],
   autoCreateViewport: true,
   launch: function() {
      appname.role = role = Ext.getStore('myStore').getAt(0).raw.role;
   }
});
```